# Am I fetching the api the wrong way in react native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

I am trying to fetch an API and use it to build an app that shows random photos of dogs. I think something is wrong with my fetch. I get an error message that says that the map function is wrong but im not sure if the error is because of the function or if I have gotten the headers wrong?

This is my code

````
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Share, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const apiKey = ``
const url = `https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search`

const App = () => { 
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState ([])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization: apiKey} })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        setPhotos(json.photos)
        console.log(json)
      })
  }, [])


    return(
     <Container>

        <Text>Hello World</Text>
         {photos.map((photo) => (

           <View key={photo.name}>
           <TouchableOpacity>
             <Text>{photo.status}</Text>  
           </TouchableOpacity> 

           <Image
             source={{uri: photo.url}}
             style={{width: 300, height: 300}} />

             </View>
         ))}
      </Container>
    );
  }

  export default App

  const Button = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    width: 200;
    background-color: grey;`

  const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  padding_top: 50;` ```
````

Comment: Please give a [mcve] including the full error and a sample of the JSON data to show its shape. Also you need to revoke the API credentials you've just posted publicly.

Comment: Agreeing with @jonrsharpe here, please delete this api key or make and make a new one, this one is compromised.

Comment: Thanks for tips, I was a little hesistant about the api. But since Im a beginner and dont know exactly where the error was I didnt know if it could be answered without seeing the api. Therefore I also added the whole code. However I removed the key and applied for a new one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So making a test my self where i use the URL you provide and your API key (which you likely should not post publicly), I was able to see what response the server sends back:

It just sends an array back

```
[
    {
        "breeds": [],
        "id": "SycZKu2Sm",
        "url": "https://cdn2.thedogapi.com/images/SycZKu2Sm_1280.jpg",
        "width": 1024,
        "height": 683
    }
]
```

Meaning where you do `setPhotos(json.photos)` `photos` is not a key in the json response, which will result in the state key `photos` is `undefined`, and when you try to run `photos.map` on undefined you will get this error.

change `setPhotos` to `setPhotos(json)` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try that. And I also removed the api-key. When I got your answer I noticed that it says photo also in the map-function Like this:  {photos.map((photo) => ( : Should I instead write {photos.map((photos) => ( since photos is what is written in setState?

Comment: Never mind It worked like you told me :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help @camillalofroth removing the API from the the question is not enough, you need to revoke the API key from the server as well, its compromised.